Recursive Incomplete Gamma Function for $a=1$
It can be shown that the incomplete Gamma function:
$$
\Gamma_X(a) = \int_0^x t^{a-1} e^{-t} \, dt
$$
Can be expressed as a recursive relationship:
$$
\Gamma_X(a) = (a-1) \ \Gamma_X(a-1) - x^{a-1} \ e^{-x}
$$
However for the first expression:
$$
\Gamma_X(a=1) = 1 -e^{-x}
$$
while for the recursive expression
$$
\Gamma_X(a=1) = 0  - e^{-x}
$$
Where is the error I did?

recursive formula is correct only for $a>1$
